# How do I remove the cup holders of my 2016 Mazda 6?

Tags: mazda, mazda-6, center-console

I need to remove the cup holders in my 2016 Mazda 6 for cleaning. I tried fumbling with it gently to see if it lifts out, but I had no luck. I'm afraid of breaking it. Can anyone tell me how to remove the cup holders?

Comment: I don't know if they did it differently for the 3rd generation Mazda6, but on the 2nd gen, you just have to pull up (straight up) on the cup holders to remove them There are some interference tabs which hold it in place. I don't think I'd take my word for this on yours, though. Hopefully someone with some experience can help you out with a real answer.